# How to do something every second while waiting for await function?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, timeout

I want to wait an `await myFunction()` and while I wait until myFunction() returns I want to `console.log("1 second awaited")` every 1 second. I tried using `.then()` but got no results, maybe I am bad at understanding promises.

P.S.: `myFunction()` fetch an ajax response and is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an interval before the Promise starts, and clear it once the Promise resolves (or rejects, if you wish):

```
const intervalID = setInterval(() => {
  console.log('1 second awaited');
}, 1000);
try {
  await myFunction();
} catch(e) {
  // ...
}
clearInterval(intervalId);
```

Or, if the `catch` can throw too (which it probably shouldn't):

```
const intervalID = setInterval(() => {
  console.log('1 second awaited');
}, 1000);
try {
  await myFunction();
} catch(e) {
  // ...
} finally {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
}
```

Might look nicer without `await`:

```
const intervalID = setInterval(() => {
  console.log('1 second awaited');
}, 1000);
myFunction()
  .catch(handleErrors) // either make sure handleErrors doesn't throw, or catch again
  .then(() => {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  });
```

Comment: I personally would use `try finally`, just in case there is an error in the `catch`.